# NXP 88W9098 PCIe Card shows up as "Ethernet Controller"

Tags: drivers, wireless, kernel

I'm running Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS on the NXP FRWY-LS1012A Development Board (Kernel 5.10.35). I've successfully loaded the two kernel modules required for the NXP PCIe 88W9098 WiFi card (mlan and moal), yet the card still shows up as two Ethernet Controllers (one for each antenna, the Ethernet Interfaces are legit). Has anyone seen this issue before and/or know how to correct it? (see photo)

Thanks[image]

Comment: Post results from terminal for `lspci -nnk|grep -iA3 net; sudo dmesg | grep firmware; lsmod | grep cfg`  Please don't post pictures of terminal output as you can copy and paste it as text

Comment: `lspci -nnk|grep -iA3 net
01:00.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Marvell Technology Group Ltd. Device [1b4b:2b43] (rev 03)
 Subsystem: Marvell Technology Group Ltd. Device [1b4b:2b43]
 Kernel driver in use: wlan_pcie
01:00.1 Ethernet controller [0200]: Marvell Technology Group Ltd. Device [1b4b:2b44] (rev 03)
 Subsystem: Marvell Technology Group Ltd. Device [1b4b:2b44]
 Kernel driver in use: wlan_pcie`

Comment: `[    0.000000] psci: PSCIv1.1 detected in firmware.
[    4.083919] pfe_firmware_init
[   67.314504] Request firmware: nxp/pcieuart9098_combo_v1.bin
[   68.150521] Request firmware: nxp/pcieuart9098_combo_v1.bin`

Comment: `lsmod | grep cfg` returns nothing

Comment: @Jeremy31 Card seems to be working as it should, just surprised it shows up as an Ethernet Controller